# can not use @angular/cli@1.6.3 & bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3 together

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

adding bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3 to a project created by @angular/cli@1.6.3 cause an error and the project can not be started. When I downgrade to bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 everything is fine. Is there a way to use bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3 with @angular/cli@1.6.3 or not?